# Facing type conversion issues in swift language

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift language. I am trying to convert below C++ function to Swift function as below.

C++ function:

```
int test(test_type type, request_info_t *request, size_t request_len)
{
  size_t size = request_len;
  int mib[] = {0,0,0,0,0};
   
  int ret = sysctl(mib, 5, request, &size, NULL, 0)
  return ret;
}
```

Swift function:

```
func test( type: test_type, request: request_info_t, request_len: size_t) -> Int64
{
  let size: Int = request_len
  let mib: [Int]= [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   
  let val: Int32 = sysctl(mib, 5, request, size, nil, 0)
  return val
}
```

But I am facing below issues with arguments at sysctl(). Could any one please help to fix this.

- Error due to first argument mib: Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?'
- Error due to third argument request: Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?'
- Error due to fourth argument size: Cannot convert value of type 'request_info_t' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer?'

Comment: What are `test_type` and `request_info_t`?

Comment: test_type is enum and request_info_t is struct

Answer (score 0):

- First, the type of the first parameter of sysctl in Swift is UnsafeMutablePointer!.

int in C++ (of Apple's platform) is equivalent to Int32 in Swift, not Int and declare mib as an Array of Int32 and mutable.

- Second, the type of the third parameter of sysctl in Swift is UnsafeMutableRawPointer!.

Pass arbitrary mutable pointer to UnsafeMutableRawPointer!, but the second parameter of test in Swift is declared as request_info_t, not a pointer. It does not match the type of second parameter in C++, it's request_info_t * -- pointer to request_info_t.
Declare the second parameter of test in Swift as pointer to request_info_t.

- Third, the type of the fourth parameter of sysctlin Swift is UnsafeMutablePointer!.

Pass an inout parameter (&) of Int to UnsafeMutablePointer!.

- Fourth, the return type of test in C++ is int, as already said, its equivalent in Swift is Int32.

After including all such things, code should look like this:

```
func test(type: test_type, request: UnsafeMutablePointer<request_info_t>, request_len: size_t) -> Int32 {
        var size: Int = request_len 
        var mib: [Int32] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        
        let val: Int32 = sysctl(&mib, 5, request, &size, nil, 0)
        return val
}
```